# Loading Script using $.getScript callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I'm loading the Google Maps API using jquery $.getScript like so

```
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?async=2&callback=GMapsInit");
```

You can see that the URL has the callback function `GMapsInit`. Does the `GMapsInit` function get called after the script is loaded and executed, or simply after its loaded and not necessarily executed?

Comment: Do you encounter any issue?

Comment: Nope. No issues at all

Answer (score 1):

The callback is called when the script is loaded AND executed.

This is why you have to use a callback when you load Google Maps.

Comment: It could be executed before any async operation in script included BUT i'm not sure there is any

Comment: `also why you can't give a closure as a second argument to $.getScript()` The success `getScript()` callback will be called *after* the callback  set in URI http://jsfiddle.net/p6gp13ju/

Comment: But the GMapsInit() function is already being called in the URL. What would adding this do exactly?

Comment: Well if it works as @A. Wolff said, you don't need to put a callback int the URL. You just put your code in the closure with the get script. It's one solution or the other, it's just a matter of what you prefer.

Comment: @PeterPan666 ya exactly but i'd suggest to use the callback url parameter instead because this is how, i suppose, works this API